# How to access wikidata revision history?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to access wikidata revision history page using SPARQL or wikimedia-API for the Item Eden Hazard (Q214204) as an example, to get the latest and oldest timestamps values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get wikidata first and last revision timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567772/get-wikidata-first-and-last-revision-timestamp)

Comment: @StanislavKralin when I used the aswer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567772/get-wikidata-first-and-last-revision-timestamp , first timestamp revision was before wikidata was even launched ```first timestamp: "timestamp": "2004-07-16T02:43:38Z" ``` while wikidata was launched en 2012!!

Comment: on history endpoint: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
 PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX hist: <http://wikiba.se/history/ontology#>

select distinct ?s ?date {
  ?s schema:about wd:Q939047 ;
  schema:dateCreated ?date
  filter(?date = ?last || ?date = ?first)
{
    select (min(?date) as ?first) (max(?date) as ?last) {
  ?s schema:about wd:Q939047; 
     schema:dateCreated ?date}
}
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser it returned: "no matching records found" and I used wikidata query service https://query.wikidata.org/

Comment: and I said *"on history endpoint"* ... https://wdhqs.wmflabs.org/

Comment: to get the revisions with the Wikimedia API, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577244/get-wikidata-oldest-and-latest-revision-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

There’s a fun way to access mediawiki data that happens to be excellent for such metadata: https://quarry.wmflabs.org

Set the database to `wikidatawiki_p`. Here‘s the SQL:

```sql
SELECT MAX(rev_timestamp), MIN(rev_timestamp) 
FROM page JOIN revision 
ON page.page_id = revision.rev_page 
WHERE page_title = "Q214204";
```

I’ve published the query here: https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/57342

Answer (score 0):

Answers above have described how to get the timestamps of older versions of a Wikidata object. To get the contents of an older version of the wikidata-object you can use the [MediaWiki Revisions API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions).

The following query gives you the contents of two named revisions of [Q42175289](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42175289)

[https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=revisions&revids=580231008|580231017&rvprop=timestamp|comment|content&rvslots=main](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=revisions&revids=580231008%7C580231017&rvprop=timestamp%7Ccomment%7Ccontent&rvslots=main)

whereas the following gives you the first 3 revisions of the same item (with contents)

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Q42175289&formatversion=2&rvprop=ids%7Ccomment%7Ccontent%7Ccontentmodel&rvslots=main&rvlimit=3&rvdir=newer

Comment: For those, like me, who originally found this post because they wanted to work with Structured Data on Wikimedia Commons. Note that you need to replace `rvslots=main` by `rvslots=mediainfo`.