# how to create sub schema of wiki data using wDumper for different time frame

Tags: schema, sparql, wikidata

I want to use WDumper to get sub-schema, however the sub-schema needs to be version or year specific. For instance, I need  disease sub-schema of Wikidata  for each of the following years: 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020,2021, 2022, and 2023, but I can only receive it for the current time. Could someone please explain to me how to retrieve various versions of the wikidata sub-schema using WDumper? How can I use this date filter?

I can't try to solve it.

Comment: do you really mean a "sub-*schema*" or do you mean the subgraph of Wikidata? I guess the latter. Regarding your question, this is clearly not covered by WDumper. What you would need is some access to the revision history of all the disease related entities of Wikidata. Some hints regarding that have been provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597841/how-to-access-wikidata-revision-history . A creation date is still not available in the RDF dataset, so SPARQL would be no option: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T151539

Comment: I want to download more than one entity of a topic as a package. I know that we can download different item or entity using api. But i need a sub schema or sub graph that have multiple entity and I need to download as a version wise